# Bootstrap Toggle Button Not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Django Project and I see navbar error after adding a few script tags. It worked before.
Navbar is moving down but it is not moving back to its position. I see after commenting a few script tags it works. I'm unsure what it needs exactly. HTML code below.Thanks

I could understand that we need to add few js files. But what needs to be added is my question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <title>Cricket Management</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,500,600,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datepicker.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.timepicker.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/flaticon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-black">About</h4>
              <p class="text-muted">CrickyMac is an Indian cricket news website owned by Times Internet. It features news, articles and live coverage of cricket matches including videos, scorecards, text commentary, player stats and team rankings. Their website also offers a mobile app. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-black">Contact</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="text-black">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="text-black">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:arunkumar6894@gmail.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top" class="text-black">Email me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{% static 'Hello.jpg'%}" class="img-rounded" alt="WorldCup" width="80" height="50"> 
            <em>CrickyMac</em>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>    
  </header>
    {% block content%}
    <div class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style="background-image: url('{% static 'backgroundImage.jpg'%}');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.1">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-center" data-scrollax-parent="true">
          <div class="col-md-11 ftco-animate text-center">
           <h1 class="mb-4">Howdy Partner !!!! CRICKET- not just a game It’s an emotion, For Team Details click Below.</h1>
            <p><a href="{% url 'teamlist' %}" class="btn btn-primary mr-md-4 py-3 px-4">Teams <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                  <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">Stats</strong>
                  <h3 class="mb-0">Matches and Results</h3>
                  <p class="card-text mb-auto">Get to Know all the scheduled Matches, News and Other Updates in regards to the IPL, ODI, TEST</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button">Fixures &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img src="{% static 'fixtures.jpg'%}" class="img-rounded" alt="WorldCup" width="200" height="250">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                  <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">Rankings</strong>
                  <h3 class="mb-0">Points Table</h3>
                  <p class="mb-auto">Cricket Council ranking for One Day International (ODI) cricket teams. Discover latest ICC rankings table, predict upcoming matches, see points and rating.</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button">Points Table &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img src="{% static 'point.jpg'%}" class="img-rounded" alt="WorldCup" width="200" height="250"> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.timepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/scrollax.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/google-map.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>  

  <footer class="text-muted">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="float-right">
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
      </p>
      <p>CricketManagement@2020 &copy; “Life is simply a cricket match, with temptation as the bowler.”</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Talking about the section above the nav opening and closing? Seems to work fine

Comment: @abney317   Yes But i could not see it is working in my local. Even in the Run code snippet i see an error throwing below after hitting the toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems which I can see in your code which is causing this problem is:

1. You have called bootstrap 4 CDN in your code's head.
2. you have also called bootstrap JS files in your footer

   3. you have called proper.js which is a dependency for BS 4, jQuery is needed for BS and proper before.

Solution:

1. Remove bootstrap CDN from your head
2. add it to bottom of your page,
3. make sure jquery is called before BootStrap's js and proper.js.
4. don't call any js file twice, weather its jquery or BS files.

   now I am updating your code in this edit... check now and don't forget to checkpoints below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <title>Cricket Management</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,500,600,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datepicker.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.timepicker.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/flaticon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-black">About</h4>
              <p class="text-muted">CrickyMac is an Indian cricket news website owned by Times Internet. It features news, articles and live coverage of cricket matches including videos, scorecards, text commentary, player stats and team rankings. Their website also offers a mobile app. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-black">Contact</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="text-black">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="text-black">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:arunkumar6894@gmail.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top" class="text-black">Email me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{% static 'Hello.jpg'%}" class="img-rounded" alt="WorldCup" width="80" height="50"> 
            <em>CrickyMac</em>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>    
  </header>
    {% block content%}
    <div class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style="background-image: url('{% static 'backgroundImage.jpg'%}');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.1">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-center" data-scrollax-parent="true">
          <div class="col-md-11 ftco-animate text-center">
           <h1 class="mb-4">Howdy Partner !!!! CRICKET- not just a game It’s an emotion, For Team Details click Below.</h1>
            <p><a href="{% url 'teamlist' %}" class="btn btn-primary mr-md-4 py-3 px-4">Teams <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                  <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">Stats</strong>
                  <h3 class="mb-0">Matches and Results</h3>
                  <p class="card-text mb-auto">Get to Know all the scheduled Matches, News and Other Updates in regards to the IPL, ODI, TEST</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button">Fixures &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img src="{% static 'fixtures.jpg'%}" class="img-rounded" alt="WorldCup" width="200" height="250">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                  <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">Rankings</strong>
                  <h3 class="mb-0">Points Table</h3>
                  <p class="mb-auto">Cricket Council ranking for One Day International (ODI) cricket teams. Discover latest ICC rankings table, predict upcoming matches, see points and rating.</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button">Points Table &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img src="{% static 'point.jpg'%}" class="img-rounded" alt="WorldCup" width="200" height="250"> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}  
<footer class="text-muted">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="float-right">
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
      </p>
      <p>CricketManagement@2020 &copy; “Life is simply a cricket match, with temptation as the bowler.”</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.timepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/scrollax.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/google-map.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
  

  </body>  

  

</html>
```

I have updated you code, check now, the mistakes you are still doing was match with your code.

1. You were calling bootstrap and proper js and jquery cdn many times before body closing tag.
2. you were calling footer after body closing tag which is wrong. all your html tags need to be within the body.
3. you were using a link tag to add script files, which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by "add it to bottom of your page"?

Comment: After footer , where you have added your other script files... It's best practice to always call scripts before body's closing tag or just after footer. And all your css in head of the html.

Comment: Thanks. I have done all your said changes. It still not working in my local. I have updated my changed snippet. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I will Need to hit it three times to move up.

Comment: It helps. Thanks